# Lcdui and midlet packages does not exist in netbeans

Tags: java, java-me, netbeans7.0, java-wireless-toolkit

in my netbeans 7.0.1 there is an error package does not exist for lcdui and midlet package,I have added `java(TM) SDK platform and Wireless toolkit platform` but still i'm gettin the error..here is the screenshot.
[image: http://www.servimg.com/image_preview.php?i=2&u=16857357]

Please help me.

Comment: stackoverflow also provides the possibility to upload images - that makes it a lot easier to view

Comment: Yeah,but while i'm posting this error came.so only i posted like this.   `We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating the Java application. Because that project icon (coffee cup) shows Java Application. ;) Don't create the Java Application for Java ME mobile application. Choose the Java ME application under Java ME. Mobile icon showing while create the Java ME mobile application.

**File -> New -> Java ME -> Mobile Application or Mobile Class Library.**

Don't create **File -> New -> Java -> Java Application** for mobile application. For more info look this article, [How to create a simple MIDlet application with NetBeans.](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/01/02/j2me-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-midlet-application-with-netbeans/)